# how to solve "is not a function" in node js with rethink db?

Tags: node.js, rethinkdb

```
TypeError: pollObject.addNewPolls is not a function
    at /home/imerit/iReNO/controllers/polls.js:23:16
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/home/imerit/iReNO/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
    at next (/home/imerit/iReNO/node_modules/express/lib/router/route.js:131:13)
    at next (/home/imerit/iReNO/node_modules/express/lib/router/route.js:125:14)
    at Route.dispatch (/home/imerit/iReNO/node_modules/express/lib/router/route.js:112:3)
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/home/imerit/iReNO/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
    at /home/imerit/iReNO/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:277:22
    at Function.process_params (/home/imerit/iReNO/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:330:12)
    at next (/home/imerit/iReNO/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:271:10)
    at Function.handle (/home/imerit/iReNO/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:176:3)
    at router (/home/imerit/iReNO/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:46:12)
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/home/imerit/iReNO/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
    at trim_prefix (/home/imerit/iReNO/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:312:13)
    at /home/imerit/iReNO/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:280:7
    at Function.process_params (/home/imerit/iReNO/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:330:12)
    at next (/home/imerit/iReNO/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:271:10)
```

This is the error i am getting while trying to call the url.
polls.js code is given below.

```
"use strict";
var rethinkdb = require('rethinkdb');
var db = require('./db');
var async = require('async');

class polls {
  addNewPolls(pollData,callback) {
    async.waterfall([
      function(callback) {
        db.connectToDb(function(err,connection) {
          if(err) {
            return callback(true,"Error connecting to database");
          }
          callback(null,connection);
        });
      },
      function(connection,callback) {
        rethinkdb.table('poll').insert({
            "question" : pollData.question,
            "polls" : pollData.polls
        }).run(connection,function(err,result) {
          connection.close();
          if(err) {
            return callback(true,"Error happens while adding new polls");
          }
          callback(null,result);
        });
      }
    ],function(err,data) {
      callback(err === null ? false : true,data);
    });
  }
}

module.exports = polls;
```

I am very new to node js. is there any syntax problem? I have created controller, model, and `app.js`. My controller contains `home.js`, `index.js`, `polls.js` and models contains `db.js` and `polls.js`. I am trying to hit

```
http://localhost:3000/polls
```

I have used [This Link](https://codeforgeek.com/2016/03/building-real-time-polling-app-rethinkdb-nodejs/) as reference

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you should new the database object first:

```
var dbObject = new db();
  dbObject.connectToDb(function(err,connection) {
  // your code here.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

seems your forget to instanciate the class :

```
class A{ b(){console.log("sdsd");}}
A.b(); // undefined
(new A()).b(); // ok
```

Replace module.exports by :

```
module.exports = new polls();
```

Comment: now i am getting "TypeError: pollModel is not a constructor" after replacing "module.exports = polls;" with "module.exports = new polls();"